Quarkus SmallRye JWT validation configuration
I'm trying to validate a token from an AWS ALB and apparently the iat claim is missing (against MicroProfile JWT 1.2 spec?) so the validation fails. I didn't find any setting that could relax this requirement, any suggestions?

apparently smallrye.jwt.time-to-live=-1 does the trick
